# JOGL Opengl WriteCloneable in eclipse

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am following [this tutorial](http://schabby.de/jogl-example-hello-world/).

Although I did exactly same as the tutorial, even i watched the video.
Even i tried other tutorial.But all of my try, i got that error everytime.

When i click to run, a error box display and "A Java Exception has occurred."

And i see that errors in consol

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/common/type/WriteCloneable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
...
```

Even i uninstalled jdk&jre and i download last version and install.
I am using eclipse, Windows 7 home premium 64 bit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find solution.

If you get JVMUtil or WriteCloneable error with NoClassDefFoundError, you must copy that 4 library jar to java/jre/lib/ext folder.

thanks for schabby.

Comment: No it is a wrong solution, it can even break your environment, it is a very bad advice. Never copy JARs into jre/lib/ext or it will cause conflicts if an applet or an application uses the same library but in another version.

Answer (score 2):

At first, his tutorials contain several errors, I already complained in the comments of his Youtube video. I advise you to use the official tutorials in [our wiki](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and to contact us on the [official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org/) if you need some help.

Something was probably wrong in your environment or you used the 32 bits version with a 64 bits JVM. If you don't know which JARs you should use for the native libraries, just take the both and let GlueGen pick the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add all the 4 libs in your project, like this.

```
-lib
    --gluegen-rt.jar
    --gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar
    --jogl-all.jar
    --jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar
```

That works to me:)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with your classpath since the WriteCloneable class isn't being found - one or more of the jars that you need is probably missing from the build path.

In Eclipse: Right click on your project / Properties / Java Build Path / Libraries tab. Check that the JOGL libraries that you need are all there.

Comment: I checked this thousand time.
glugen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar

gluegen-rt.jar

jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar

jogl.all.jar

Comment: There was probably something dirty in your environment (several versions of the same JAR in the classpath or an environment variable point to another version or some binaries depending on another version) which leads Java to run the binary with the wrong version of the library. If you use a 64 bits JVM, you should use gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar instead of gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar (and do the same for JOGL).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I solved it by adding the dependencies for gluegen. First I only had:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

this solved the problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```